# Ext js 5 SyntaxError: unterminated string literal issue

Tags: extjs5

I test below code of Extjs5:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'try extjs text area',
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{ 
            xtype: 'textarea',
            value: ' The first line \n The second line',
            border: true,
            autoScroll: true,
            draggable: true
        }]
     }
    ).show();
```

The issue is text content contain **\n** as below  :
**value: ' The first line \n The second line',**

and it will get error:
**SyntaxError: unterminated string literal**

But I need to display a new line in textarea . What's correct solutions for this ?

BTW , This issue is caused by Tree Panel render :

I have a render method like below in MainController.js :

```
    renderLogs: function (logs, p, record) {
     return logs?  '<div><img src="default-more.png" /
       onclick="Ext.create(\'Ext.window.Window\', /
         { title: \'try extjs text area\', /
           width: 900,height: 500, /
           layout: \'fit\', /
           items: [{xtype: \'textarea\', /
           value: \'"+logs+"\', /
           border: true,autoScroll: true,draggable: true}]}).show(); "> /
      </img></div>' : '';
   }
```

So if logs content **\n** , it will get ERROR - SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside 'items' parameter: text is not correct 'sub-parameter' of 'textarea', 'value' is the correct. That was the problem. Correct code is: 
`Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'try extjs text area',
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: { 
            xtype: 'textarea',
            value: ' The first line \n The second line',
            border: true,
            autoScroll: true,
            draggable: true
        }}
    ).show();`

Comment: Hi, Adarsh , Thanks for checking this issue , This is my issue type error , Now I changed to value: ' The first line \n The second line', My core issue is during renderXXX , I need to create a new Window to pop up log info , So I must return as string .

Comment: @Jerry Cai : ok, so if you have \n in a string var (logs) then it will return new line char, which making problem in concatenation, so first replace it to \\n... [`logs.replace("\n","\\n")`]. I m not sure but try this, and tell me...